# Какой самый простой движок/конструктор/engine для 3D игры не игры?

Tags: разработка-игр, конструктор, 3d, движок

Нужен очень простой (но желательно не совсем уж пиксельный 240*320 для CGA/EGA мониторов :) ) движок/конструктор для создания псевдо игры 3D (не перепутайте, не игры псевдо-3D). Нужно создать бродилку на пару комнат с коридором или 3D лабиринт c очень простыми простыми предметами внутри (кубики, шарики), jpeg-картинки. Ни персонажей, врагов/фрагов/ботов, ни оружия, ни взаимодействия с предметами не нужно.
Желательно, но не обязательно что-нибудь из этих характеристик:

1. Легкий для освоения без необходимости реального программирования и дополнительного освоения сложных 3D программ на первом этапе.
2. Если есть программирование - то желательно python или LUA.
3. Минимальный размер итогового файла (*.exe + данные/карты отдельно или всё в одном exe до 100 мб).
4. Легально бесплатный хотя бы для некоммерческого использования, лучше open source.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, во мне говорит энтузиазм неофита, но, мне кажется, что Unity 3D - это практичеки единственный "популярный" кандидат.

Пункты 1 и 4 - вроде бы без замечаний, по пункту 2 - там есть программирование на C#, но, поверьте, это такой C#, что разницы с python или LUA вы особо не заметите. Зато полинтернета справочных руководств и уроков

По пункту 3 - не могу ничего сказать, потому что еще не собрал ни одного итогового проекта :-)

Но я смотрю вот на что: платформа развивается, и сообщество вокруг неё - очень большое и активное. Так что, может, даже лишняя сотня мегабайт - не очень большая плата за комфорт разработки?